# How to run Office365 powershell in Azure Webjob?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a program which uses Office 365 Powershell to query O365 information. it works fine. Now, we want to use Azure and put this part into a webjob.

Now, we can pass the credentail into the powershell (using C# code), but when it runs as a webjob, it always shows error, see the screen shot. It says that the cmdlet is not recognized.

[image]

I know even on our local machine, we will need to install Windows Azure Active Directory Module to run Office365 powershell. Could the error be because in the Azure, it does not have this module?

So the question is: is there a way to install/integrate this into Azure webjob? or, is there other way that we could run Office 365 powershell in Azure webjob?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551290/running-azure-powershell-commands-from-a-webjob ?

Comment: There's a  bit more detail in my similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946244/need-to-call-msol-cmdlets-from-a-webjob.

Comment: thanks, paulr. based on my current research, there is no way to do that in webjob yet, although I could be wrong.