# Azure Webjob (Powershell): The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-powershell

I have created a zip file that contains my `Powershell` script and `.publishsettings` file for authentication. When I create and run my `WebJob`,
 I get the error:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile : The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have checked using Kudu Console that the file is present both on the **Source** and **Working** Directory.
 This is the command that I am running:

```
$pubsettings = "dummy-credentials.publishsettings"
$actualpath = "$PSScriptRoot\$pubsettings"
echo "$actualpath"
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile $actualpath
```

This is running perfectly on my Local Machine. Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As [Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495124.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in the .7.2 version of the Microsoft Azure PowerShell module.
And according the answer of [Running Azure PowerShell commands from a webjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551290/running-azure-powershell-commands-from-a-webjob) provided by an architect on the Azure team, and an engineer of KUDU.

Azure PowerShell is not currently supported from the sandbox in which WebJobs runs.

And also as the suggestion of him:

> One potential workaround is to do ARM requests directly, though that's a bit more work (and you still need to auth using Service Principal). You could also write C# code to make the calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gary. But, I do not completely understand / agree. If Azure Powershell is not supported, shouldn't the errors be of the kind "Command not found" instead of "Command is running but cannot find the file"?

Comment: @Flemin, we consulted internally on this issue and due to the current sandbox security restriction imposed on Azure Web sites/web job, running Azure PS command in this environment is currently not supported and most likely often problematic. Product group is aware of this limitation and working to address this, there is no ETA we can share at this point. At your convenient, could you please try to leverage the workaround that pointed out in Gary's post?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Ming. Unfortunately, I won't be able to do ARM requests directly like @Gary pointed out as I'm actually trying to interact with a cloud service (which I believe is not moved to ARM yet). I'll post a different question so as not to deviate from the current topic. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, @Flemin. You're always welcome to post any inquiries that you have, have a nice day.